how to create transparent activity without action bar without title bar?
I've tried multiple ways to create a transparent full screen activity but the top and bottom bar are ways present.
here is the code I use:
in the styles.mxl
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!--on below line we are setting background as transparent color-->
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!--on below line we are displaying the windowNotitle as true as we are not displaying our status bar-->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--on below line we are setting our window background as transparent color-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!--on below line we are setting color background cache hint as null-->
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <!--on below line we are adding a window translucent as true-->
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <!--on below line we are adding a window animationstyle-->
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>

in manifest.xml
    <activity
        android:name=".myActivity"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="test_string"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent">
    </activity>

When the activity is triggered it always show the screen like the below image:

How can I make the top and bottom dark bar invisible?
Thanks a lot!! I really tried different way....
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" doesn't work as well.

Does this answer your question? Android Completely transparent Status Bar?
